# How to make Hadoop Map Reduce process multiple files in a single run ?

Tags: hadoop

For Hadoop Map Reduce program when we run it by executing this command **$hadoop jar my.jar DriverClass input1.txt hdfsDirectory**. How to make Map Reduce process multiple files( input1.txt & input2.txt ) in a single run ?

Comment: do you mean input*.txt or handful files like 1.txt, 2,txt?

Comment: i mean 1.txt, 2.txt, .....

Comment: @user2192023 did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Like that:

```
hadoop jar my.jar DriverClass hdfsInputDir hdfsOutputDir
```

where

- `hdfsInputDir` is the path on HDFS where your input files are stored (i.e., the parent directory of `input1.txt` and `input2.txt`)
- `hdfsOutputDir` is the path on HDFS where the output will be stored (it should not exist before running this command).

Note that your input should be copied on HDFS before running this command. 
To copy it to HDFS, you can run:

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal localPath hdfsInputDir
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your small files problem. for every file mapper will run.

A small file is one which is significantly smaller than the HDFS block size (default 64MB). If you’re storing small files, then you probably have lots of them (otherwise you wouldn’t turn to Hadoop), and the problem is that HDFS can’t handle lots of files.

Every file, directory and block in HDFS is represented as an object in the namenode’s memory, each of which occupies 150 bytes, as a rule of thumb. So 10 million files, each using a block, would use about 3 gigabytes of memory. Scaling up much beyond this level is a problem with current hardware. Certainly a billion files is not feasible.

**solution**

**HAR files**

Hadoop Archives (HAR files) were introduced to HDFS in 0.18.0 to alleviate the problem of lots of files putting pressure on the namenode’s memory. HAR files work by building a layered filesystem on top of HDFS. A HAR file is created using the hadoop archive command, which runs a MapReduce job to pack the files being archived into a small number of HDFS files. To a client using the HAR filesystem nothing has changed: all of the original files are visible and accessible (albeit using a har:// URL). However, the number of files in HDFS has been reduced.

**Sequence Files**

The usual response to questions about “the small files problem” is: use a SequenceFile. The idea here is that you use the filename as the key and the file contents as the value. This works very well in practice. Going back to the 10,000 100KB files, you can write a program to put them into a single SequenceFile, and then you can process them in a streaming fashion (directly or using MapReduce) operating on the SequenceFile. There are a couple of bonuses too. SequenceFiles are splittable, so MapReduce can break them into chunks and operate on each chunk independently. They support compression as well, unlike HARs.  Block compression is the best option in most cases, since it compresses blocks of several records (rather than per record).